# How do I correctly identify the object in a sentence?

Tags: objects

How do I correctly identify the object in a sentence?

Here are two examples I am confused about.

1. She rose from her chair.

   On a website, I read that this sentence doesn't contain any object. But I believe that since the "chair" is receiving the action of the verb "rose", it must be an object.
2. He is working on a project.

   Is project an object here?

Kindly tell me  how can I easily sort out objects in different sentences.

Comment: No: the NP "her chair" is object complement of the preposition "from" and not directly related to the verb, hence not direct object of "rose". For "chair" to be object, it would have to be the impossible *"She rose her chair". Same in 2: You might do well to do some research on objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple thing that you can do is to isolate the verb and put "whom" or "what" in front of it.

Let us take your first example.
She rose from her chair.
If we isolate the verb and insert what or whom in front of it, the whole question seems ridiculous and as explained by @BillJ we need to do the impossible by writing - "She rose her chair".

As per the definition of the object- one that receives the action- chair might seem a good choice, but in actuality, "her chair" will be counted as an object complement and not as an object.

Do the same analysis for the second one. Hope it helps!